# Will C# merge with native C++ compiler?

Tags: c#, c++

According to this post :

http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/Coffeehouse/MS-working-on-a-same-compiler-for-C-AND-C--Not-in-incubation-but-for-production-

How much truth is in this post? Should it be taken seriously by hardcore C++ programmers (game devs etc)??

Edit : There's another purpose to this question... Will C# be backward compatible with C++?

Comment: +1 because the linked job postings on the Microsoft site do indeed mention a compiler for c# and C++ https://careers.microsoft.com/jobdetails.aspx?jid=81769

Comment: I wonder why its not in the news these days....

Comment: Both  C# and C++ can benefit from the same optimisations performed over a common IR, therefore it might make sense to have a unified compiler.

Comment: Hmm but will C# be backwards compatible with C++?

Comment: Why should it be backward-compatible? These languages are too different, which does not mean they cannot both share the same compiler middle layer (while still targeting the different backends).

Comment: E.g., the polyhedral analysis (which they've mentioned explicitly in the ad) will be exactly the same for both languages, with some additional dependency on aliasing analysis for the C++ frontend.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not a chance in hell. It would take the most drastic refactoring of a language ever to make it work with C++ and it would break every inch of existing C# code. They're most likely just trying to share the same native code generation framework.

Answer (score 6):

Probably incorrect in the specifics.  MS already has a native MSIL compiler in the form of Ngen. It wouldn't surprise me if both Ngen and cl used the same code gen back end so that they share improvements like the mentioned auto vectorization.

Comment: No, cl does not share any common backend with ngen.